# What is GlanceViewMk

Tags: settings, notifications

I found an app called "GlanceViewMk" within my notification and sounds settings menu. If I allow it, "GlanceViewMk will be able to read all the notifications you receive, which may include personal information such as contact names and messages sent to yo. It will also be able to dismiss these notifications or select actions related to them."

What to I gain by allowing this?

Comment: What is your device? It seems this is exclusive to Samsung device with Quick Glance feature.

Answer (score 2):

Since Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9500 was upgraded to Android Lollipop, got that bug called GlanceViewMk. The only solution I found was to root the device and remove the GlanceViewMk with the app you like better (I used Titanium Backup pro).

The battery stop draining and all apps are now visible on the sound notification settings.

Comment: What is it responsible of doing though?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you own a **Samsung** device. 
Go to your **Settings** where you can control the **gesture settings** and look for (I think it's called) "**Quick Check**" - the gesture where you wave your hand over the turned-off screen to see notifications and the clock. 
May be useful but I didn't use it that much.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the sound and notifications in settings, then open Notification access and turn off glanceviewmk access.

Comment: Give us the screenshot, Also try explaining the steps in brief.

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung S4 Android 5.0.1 select: Settings → My device → Motions and gesture → Air gestures → enable Quick glance.

If you have enabled it, when the screen is off you can wave your hand over the sensor at top of screen and it will show you a status screen. See "Try it" button in  *Quick glance* settings.

The checkbox under menu "sounds and notification"; "notification access" when selected allows the second row of 9 icons to be displayed (in this example pic), i.e. those normally shown at top of S4 android notification shade.

[image: example quick glance screen]